# Failed to create directory in Android Oreo (API 26)

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-8.0-oreo

I have already read the documentation for Android Oreo's Behavior and changes.

I know there is different procedure to create file directory for Android Oreo (API 26)

**Code :**

```
 File mediaStorageDir = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "MyDirectory");
        Log.v("HEREEEEE","YES");
    } else {
        mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + File.separator + "MyDirectory");
    }

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Toast.makeText(RecordVideoActivity.this, "Failed to create directory MyDirectory.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But every time i am getting toast of ***Failed to create directory MyDirectory.***
I am able to `Log.v("HEREEEEE","YES");` also but don't know it's not creating directory.

Advanced help would be appreciated.!

Comment: WHy do you have that if Build.VERSION check?  The File(File, String) constructor exists all the way back to Android 1.

Comment: First , i was not checking that. But i was getting the error. so i have tried this way

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you suggest me what i should change or why this error occurring ??

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue.  Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Comment: Yes I have already applied all necessary permissions

Comment: `there is different procedure to create file directory for Android Oreo (API 26)`. No. Not at all. But since Android 6 you need to ask the user at run time to confirm requested permissions.

Comment: Yes i know that we must apply run-time permission for `API 23>=.`. I have already applied  `private static final String[] VIDEO_PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    };`

But while doing changes in code and doing undo this was removed  `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` accidentally. So there was problem.

Answer (score 1):

Post Lollipop you have to ask for permission, you can look for the answer in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/5164673)

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Permission result callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //Create your Directory here
    }
}
```