# mkdir() or mkdirs() not working on Android API 26

Tags: android, file, android-8.0-oreo

**Following code is working with other APIs but 26**

```
public static boolean cretaeDir()
{
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.MEDIA_SHARED).getAbsolutePath();
    java.io.File folder = new java.io.File(dir + "/SomeFolderName");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        try{
            if(folder.mkdir()) {
                Log.e("Creating Folder", "Success");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.e("Creating Folder", "Failed");
                return false;
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Before some one ask, Yeah the permissions have been granted and also uses-permission present in the Manifest file.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.package.name">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />


<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application/>
```

**Test Device is Samsung S8, Running 8.0.0**

Comment: I know you have written permissions have been granted but does this include a `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE runtime permission`?

Comment: Yes this function is only called when user have granted the permission.

Comment: Just to be certain you asked permission as described in the answer to this question :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217725/failed-to-create-directory-in-android-oreo-api-26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by the following way as I have no other option left and I have tried all the suggested solutions. Maybe the error is device dependent or whatever, but it has nothing to do with API 26 as I have upgraded one of my test devices to API 26 and the old function did worked.

The following code is working on all devices.

```
 File file = MyApplication.getInstance().getDir("BUZZ",MODE_PRIVATE);
 cacheDir = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Yes this works as you now use a private folder for your app. For such a folder you do not need any permission in manifest or at runtime.  So you did it wrong with the permissions.

Comment: `cacheDir = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);` That is ugly code. Change to `cacheDir = new File(file, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);`

Comment: Yeah as I have tried everything but didn't worked for me so the only option I see is use Applications Private Folder. And the permissions are removed from the manifest file as I have changed to private folder.

Comment: Did you also remove the code used for asking the user to confirm the requested prmissions at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
File fsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String filePath = fsd.getAbsolutePath() + "/SomeFolderName";

File dir = new File(filePath);
if(dir.isDirectory==false || !dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: are you checking the file storage? or just the logs?

Comment: Checking File Storage as well.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so this worked for me.

`RequestPermission` Methods, when asking for permission, ask `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` **before anything else**. Try it...

MainActivity.kt

```
// First permission to be asked
requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
// Then all other permissions
```

This is working for all API inclusive & levels above 26.
TBH, I don't know how, but it working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a valid folder type. You have to choose from the following options

> The type of storage directory to return. Should be one of DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PODCASTS, DIRECTORY_RINGTONES, DIRECTORY_ALARMS, DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS, DIRECTORY_PICTURES, DIRECTORY_MOVIES, DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, DIRECTORY_DCIM, or DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS. May not be null.

Your code should be something like this

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: I have tried DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, DIRECTORY_PICTURES but it did not work.

Comment: did you try using folder.mkdirs() instead of folder.mkdir()?

Comment: What is the value dir, check if is being created in file system using an explorer, also check the heirarchy

Comment: I tried creating folder manually through explorer and when i run the app it and it returned true because of  **!folder.exists()** so the path or hierarchy is correct.

Comment: attach a debugger and check result of folder.mkdirs, also check the logs if there is any error that might point in the right direction

Comment: Tried that too, found nothing.

Comment: have you checked this in any other device?

Comment: Test on HTC, Samsung S6 Edge and Lenovo Tablet working on all but S8.

Comment: i don't think this is related to API 26, test on an emulator of API 26